# Verbi ausiliari

Tags: verbs, grammar, auxiliary-verb

Buongiorno,

Volevo sapere se i verbi ausiliari sono solo "essere" e "avere".

Per esempio, se leggo, "venne scritto", sembra quasi che "venire" sia un verbo ausiliare (l'altro verbo, è, ovviamente, per chi non lo sappia, "scrivere").

Scusatemi per la mia ignoranza. Grazie per la spiegazione (anche, con spiegazioni di grammatica, se possibile).

Scusatemi per il disturbo.

Grazie.

Comment: Per curiosità: quando hai cercato spiegazioni sugli ausiliari su un motore di ricerca o, meglio, sul sito della Treccani, che cosa hai trovato?

Answer (score 3):

I verbi ausiliari propriamente detti sono solamente essere ed avere, ma si usano anche altri verbi come venire/andare/volere. Non vanno confusi con i verbi servili/modali, che indicano modalità di azione.

Fonti/Approfondimenti

- [*ausiliari, verbi* in **Enciclopedia dell'Italiano** Treccani (2010)](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-ausiliari_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/),
- [*Perché il passivo in italiano ha tre ausiliari (essere, venire, andare)?*  Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/speciali/I_perche_dell_italiano_9/02_Sanso.html)
- [*servili, verbi* in **La grammatica italiana** (2012) Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-servili_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)
- [*Sul motivo per cui il verbo venire è utilizzato come ausiliare solo nei tempi semplici e non in quelli composti* Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/sul-motivo-per-cui-il-verbo-venire-%C3%A8-utilizzato-come-ausiliare-solo-nei-tempi-semplici-e-non-in-quelli-composti/153)

Comment: Sì. Sono verbi servili.

Comment: No, ausiliari e servili hanno funzioni differenti e possono anche essere usati assieme, vedere ad es. [Ausiliare con i verbi servili (Accademia della Crusca)](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/ausiliare-con-i-verbi-servili/14). Per la differenza tra servili e ausiliari vedere anche [questo articolo di Skuola.net](https://www.skuola.net/grammatica-italiana/ausiliari-essere-avere-dovere-potere.html).